# suricata rule that could detect certain TLS errors messages

Tags: security, rules, snort, ids, suricata

I am struggling with writing a suricata rule that could detect certain TLS errors messages like
"

1. ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
2. TLSV1_Unrecognized_Name_Alert

And so on ...

Also, can Suricata/Snort, detect a fetal error, if the handshake is disabled.?!

I appreciate your advice and help,,,
Thanks,,,

A suricata/snort rule.